# What is the bash equivalent of zsh vared command?

Tags: bash, zsh

I saw that with **zsh** `vared` you can edit on the fly the specified environment variable. Is there an equivalent command for **bash**?
Thanks

Comment: This might work for you: `function vared { tmpfile=$( mktemp -t vared.XXXX )  ; echo "${!1}" > "$tmpfile" ; vim "$tmpfile" && export $1=$( cat "$tmpfile" ) ; rm "$tmpfile" ; }`. Call as e.g. `vared PATH`, edit the value in `vim` and save to change the environment variable. (`mktemp` works differently depending on OS, this call seems to work mostly as intended on RHEL and OS X).

Comment: Thanks, it's good enough for me, though not cool as zsh ;) If you'd like to provide it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything that works like `zsh`'s `vared` in `bash`, out of the box.

However, you can define a function that'll allow you to edit an environment variable's value using e.g. `vim`:

```
function vared {
  [[ $# -eq 1 ]] || { echo "Usage: vared VARNAME" >&2 ; return 1 ; }
  tmpfile=$( command mktemp -t vared.XXXX )
  echo "${!1}" > "$tmpfile"
  command vim "$tmpfile" && export $1="$(< "$tmpfile" )"
  command rm "$tmpfile"
}
```

Call it as `vared PATH`.

What does it do? It creates a temporary file, writes the current value of the specified variable into the file, and opens `vim` with the temp file as argument. Now you're expected to edit the value, save, and exit `vim` (you can exit without saving the file to skip saving changes). Afterwards, the contents of the file are set as the new variable value, the whole thing gets exported, and the temp file is removed. `command` is necessary to skip shell alias and function lookups, e.g. an `rm` alias to `rm -i` would ask before deleting the file at the end otherwise.

If the variable doesn't exist or isn't an *environment* variable, it will be afterwards.

Comment: +1. I'd use `$VISUAL` instead of hardcoding vim, and you can use `$(< "$tmpfile")` instead of cat -- `$(<` is a bash builtin

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the suggestions. I removed the UUOC. Regarding `VISUAL`: It's not set by default (at least on OS X), and checking whether it exists and adding a fallback (that would need to be personalized anyway) would unnecessarily increase the complexity here.

Answer (score 3):

in bash 4.x you can do exactly same thing like this

```
# bash
read -e -p 'edit your path: ' -i "$PATH" PATH

# zsh
vared -p 'edit your path: ' PATH
```

source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642585/read-a-variable-in-bash-with-a-default-value

docs https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html

Answer (score 0):

This is based on [thecotne's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1145186/443564), written for GNU Bash 4.3:

```
vared(){
    # Based on the zsh builtin of the same name.
    IFS= read -rei "${!1}" "$1"
}
```

Note this has some subtle differences from the Zsh builtin, e.g:

- Won't error if the variable is unset
- Checks the validity of the variable name *before* printing its value (e.g. `vared $`)
- Truncates multi-line variables.